# Finding solution of this equation in set of positive integers.

Tags: number-theory, elementary-number-theory, prime-numbers

Could you help me to obtain solutions of the equation $2^{2k+1}-n^2 =1$ in set of positive integers, where $k$ and $n$ are positive integers. In case there is no solution, how to prove it.

Thanks in advance
-Richard Sieman

Comment: It is clear that $n$ must be odd. Then $n^2+1\equiv 2\pmod{8}$. It follows that $n^2+1$ is not divisible by $4$. But the left side is if $k\gt 0$.

Answer (score 3):

There is no solution:

Let $k \geq 1$.
We have $2^{2k+1}-1=1+2+4+\ldots+2^{2k} \equiv 3  \mod 4$ which should be the square of an integer. But the only squares $\mod 4$ are $0$ and $1$.

Comment: Where $k, n$ are _positive_ integers. So there are no solutions.

Comment: Of course you are right. I'll edit it.